# How to marshall correct a structure from C to C# with explicit alignment (unmanaged dll)

Tags: c#, c, dll, alignment, unmanaged

I have to use an unmanaged dll(written in C) in my C# application.
In this dll I have a structure:

```
typedef struct {
void (*Func1)(void*, int*);
void (*Func2)(void*, int*);
} myStructure;
```

and, I have a function which use this structure as [in/out] parameter:

```
void functionInterface(myStructure* pToStruct);
```

in C#, i translate that structure as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct myStructure
{
    //defining delegate instances        
    public func1 Func1;
    public func2 Func2;
              ...
    //defining delegate types
    public delegate void Func1(void* l,int* data);
    public delegate void Func2(void* l,int* data);
              ...
}
```

and function in C#:

```
[DllImport("lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void functionInterface(ref myStructure pToStruct);
```

When calling this functionInterface(), in runtime, exceptions are rising.Like "access violation to write at ... address... " or 
"access violation to read at ... address..."

I can't find the cause, i think the problem could lie in correct alignment of members in translated structure, or stack alignment, but, I have no idea how to do it right. Or problem can be different, of another nature, which I can't detect, hope you can help me guys.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly well... As I love to say: you break it, you repair it...

C#-side:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct myStructure
{
    public Fn1 Func1;
    public Fn2 Func2;

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void Fn1(IntPtr p1, ref int p2);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void Fn2(IntPtr p1, ref int p2);
}

[DllImport("lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void functionInterface(out myStructure pToStruct);
```

And then:

```
myStructure myStructure;
functionInterface(out myStructure);

int num1 = 100, num2 = 200;
myStructure.Func1((IntPtr)0x1000, ref num1);
Console.WriteLine("C#-side: out Func1: {0}", num1);
myStructure.Func2((IntPtr)0x2000, ref num2);
Console.WriteLine("C#-side: out Func2: {0}", num2);
```

C-side: (I put all the code in a .c/.cpp file, no header)

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
    typedef struct 
    {
        void (*Func1)(void*, int*);
        void (*Func2)(void*, int*);
    } myStructure;

    void Fn1(void* p1, int* p2)
    {
        printf("C-side: Fn1: %p, %d - ", p1, *p2);
        *p2 += 1;
    }

    void Fn2(void* p1, int* p2)
    {
        printf("C-side: Fn2: %p, %d - ", p1, *p2);
        *p2 += 1;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void functionInterface(myStructure* pToStruct)
    {
        pToStruct->Func1 = Fn1;
        pToStruct->Func2 = Fn2;
    }
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: I tried to make changes like in your code, but it's not working.

Comment: @denis You are doing things in the wrong direction. Use my code and incrementally make changes so that it is like your code. Not the opposite.

Comment: @denis Note that the error could be in the C-side, or in what values you pass as the parameters, insted of being in the pinvoke C# code.

Comment: I forgot to add that in Cheader "myStructure" has an attribute alignment __attribute__(packed), and, one more thing(maybe it's important to know), the dll was written for a x32 microcontroller. The exception which is rising in runtime it shows violation for reading or writing at different addresses.